# C++ header inclusions

Tags: c++, header

Hello I'm new to `C++` so bear with me, I'm making a `header` for a `class` and I just want to know if I plan on making an `object` from another class in this one should I include that in the header? for example

```
class myClass1{

public:
    "constructor and methods here"
private:
    OtherClass oc;
    "other variables here"
};
```

I know this is a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't -- my wife will get upset if I bare with anybody but her. But yes, you'll need to include a definition of the other class before your code can define an instance of that class (and yes, this is usually done by including its header).

Comment: Yes you should include the header of OtherClass.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I strongly disagree.

Comment: @JohnDibling How will this header file recognize the OtherClass?

Comment: The *header* doesn't need to.  Only the translation unit does.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal:  See my new answer for a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since as you say that you are new at C++, this might seem a bit overkill for your immediate needs.  Keep in mind what I'm trying to teach you is not how to hack this thing up right now, but good coding skills that will transfer to future projects and real work.

A stretch goal, and a general rule of thumb that I would recommend is:

> In a header file, #include nothing, or as close to nothing as is
>   possible.

Why?  There are at least two reasons.

First, it keeps compiles fast.  This is nice, but not the *real* reason.  The real reason is:

Second, it reduces interdependence between modules and hard couplings.  An interdependence between modules is an easy thing to create, and a very difficult thing to break when it becomes a problem.

Contrary to the other answers posted here, no, you do not need to `#include` `OtherClass`'s header file in this header file.  This assertion yields two questions:

1. How is it possible to not include the header?
2. Why would you not include the header, even if it is possible not to?

In order:

The *header* file doesn't need to know anything about the definition of `OtherClass`.  Only the translation unit does.  The TU needs to know the definition of `OtherClass` before it can define `MyClass1`, but that is handled simply.  Consider:

### OtherClass.h:

```
#ifndef OTHERCLASS_H
#define OTHERCLASS_H

class OtherClass
{
};

#endif
```

### MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass
{
public:
  OtherClass mOC;
};

#endif
```

### main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "OtherClass.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
}
```

The Translation Unit here is `main.cpp` and everything it #includes.  The whole package.  Since you do not compile header files directly (eg by themselves), headers are not translation units.

I suggest that what I propose above is better than adding:

```
#include "OtherClass.h"
```

to MyClass.h because it reduces the interdependence between the two objects.

This obviously isn't a concern right now, or in a toy program such as this.  It becomes an issue later, in large & complicated codebases when you try to make changes to underlying classes.  At those times, breaking these interdependancies becomes exceedingly difficult and maybe impossible depending on how much forethought you have given your design.  This becomes a lesson learned with great difficulty.

Comment: This makes the users of your class responsible for knowing the correct order of #includes. That gets to be really obnoxious if all the classes are coded that way -- not handling their own dependencies.

Comment: @MarkkuK.: I would argue that is the respnsibility of the core inclusion files, or maybe a precompiled header.  I would also argue that programmers should understand the tools they are using, but that might be personal bias.

Comment: Agreed, they should understand the tools they are using, but they should not need to know, and should not write code that depends on, the internal workings of the classes they use. If "MyClass" decides to use "AlternateClass" for a private member instead of "OtherClass", then you have to change all your code that uses "MyClass". But maybe that is handled by your concept of "core inclusion files", if you care to explain that.

Comment: @MarkkuK.:  Sure.  Every large project I've ever worked on has had one main inclusion file that is shared by all cpp files.  Its job is to bring in all the dependant names for all the common objects.  This is often also extended to other, smaller types like `MyClass` here, which may only be needed in small parts of the system.  For this, I would create a header file, say "MyNeatoThing.h" which `#include`s everything needed to use `MyClass`, in the correct order.  Client code would only have to `include` that one file.

Comment: So, you create an extra .h file, just to handle what could have been handled by the original .h file for MyClass?

Comment: @MarkkuK.:  Yes.  Like I said, it's the kind of thing that help later when it comes time to do some low-level refactoring.

Comment: @JohnDibling This is a great response and it sort of worked, but now in my .cpp class when I try to do `MyClass::MyClass(OtherClass oc)` I get an error `MyClass does not name a type`

Comment: @rsay3:  Did you #include OtherClass from within myclass.cpp?

Comment: @rsay3:  I had no such problem.  Can you double-check your inclusions?

Comment: @JohnDibling I just double checked and my inclusions are all there, although my actual program is more involved than this example, is there a way to move this to a private conversation so I can share my full code with you?

Comment: @rsay3:  I'm about to leave for the day.  Post a link to ideone.com and I'll try to take a look when I can.

Comment: I must say, I disagree with @JohnDibling's approach. IMO, it requires more work, more code, and inhibits reuse. I would be glad to see any references that say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If oc was a pointer or a reference, then you could get by with just a forward declaration (which appears above the class statement):

```
class OtherClass;

class myClass1 {
...
```

The include statement is needed because the compiler needs to know the details of `OtherClass` to define `myClass1`.

Comment: No downvote from me becaue you did not assert that the `#include` is *required*, but I disagree with the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes include using `#include "OtherClass.h"`.  If you were using a system header or maybe something from STL, you would use: `#include <SomeSystemHeader>`

Comment: I'm, not going to downvote because you did not assert that it is required, but I disagree that OP even *should* inlucde the header.